# What is the 95% confidence interval for E(Y)?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, standard-deviation, bernoulli-distribution

A research team studied Y, the percentage of voters in favor of a candidate. The random variable Y had standard deviation o = 50%. A random sample of 800 voters was selected, and their average was y-bar(800) = 52.3%. What is the 95% confidence interval for E(Y)?

The answer is: 52.3% +- 3.46%.

Can anyone help me figure out how to find this answer? I don't know the formula to find it.

Answer (score 1):

E(Y) is nothing but the mean.  The confidence interval around the measurement is directly returned in excel through:

=CONFIDENCE(0.05, 50, 800)

note alpha is $\frac{100 - 95}{100}$.

=3.46

since this is the confidence of the mean  it is centered around 52.3

the standard deviation of the mean is $= \frac{50}{\sqrt{800}}$.  Now the z-score of a 95% confidence interval is 1.96  that can be looked up in the tables manual or through excel.  the answer is simply the product of the std of mean and the z score, 1.77*1.96.

Comment: How can I get 3.46 by hand though? Would it be as simple as 1.96 * 50/sqrt(800)?

Comment: updated the original answer with manual calculation.  you should also read about sample mean and standard deviation. on the web.  hope that helps.

Comment: note that since you already have the population mean  you do not need the sample mean.  Also, applicable if the population mean was not available, since the sample size is large we would  use  the z distribution as opposed to the t  stats.